# Ubuntu/Thunderbird: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: mysql, email, ssl, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I installed Postfix, Courier and a bunch of other e-mail related services on my Ubuntu server. The data is fetched from a MySQL database. But when I try to connect through Thunderbird, I get this error:
`ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`
Why :(? How can this be fixed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many bits in your SSL key? IIRC, you'll get this error if you use larger than a 2048 bit key.

Comment: 1024, at least `/etc/courier/imapd.cnf` says so: `default_bits = 1024`

Comment: You can check with the command `openssl rsa -text -in [keyfile]`. This may have been set by whoever created the key.

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens in Thunderbird, however against a Courier imapd ssl installed on Gentoo.

Turns out there were a bunch of broken SSL certificate symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs. Removing them fixed the problem.

```
find . -type l | (while read FN ; do test -e "$FN" || ls -ld "$FN"; done)
```